# TensorFlow: Tensor Shape vs. Numpy Array Shape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

In tf.shape(), how does the tensor's shape differ from the numpy array's shape?

*Example 1:*

```
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]]) 
tf.shape(t) 

 <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>
```

Notice tensor's shape is `(3,)` while array's shape is `[2, 2, 3]`: 2 rows, 2 columns, each row is 3 levels deep. **Where is the `(3,)` from?** And **why is the second dimension `None` after 3?**

*Example 2:*

```
c = tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
tf.shape(c)

  <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 3], dtype=int32)>
```

Note here, tensor's shape is `(2,)` matching the 2 in array's `[2, 3]`. **Why it matched here, but not in Example 1?**

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried passing a numpy array, i.e. `t = tf.constant(np.asarray([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]]))`?

Comment: call `t.shape` it will give you correct output,using `tf.shape(t)` will return shape of the shape of tensor and the numpy array is the shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor's shape is defined by the length of the numpy array's shape. 
For example -

```
t = tf.constant([[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]],[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]]]) 
tf.shape(t)
```

will output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([2, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)>
```

To get the size of the tensor, use

```
t.shape
```

instead.